# Plural of "scheme"?

Tags: grammatical-number, writing

*Scheme* is the singular form. What is the plural of *scheme*?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It is *schemes*. Though it comes from the Latin *schema*, it’s not a Latin word.

Answer (score 12):

*schemes*

Do not confuse this with *schema*, which is not the plural of *scheme*, but the singular form of *schemata*.

Comment: “schemas” is also widely accepted as a plural of “schema”. In what I read, it is also much more used.